# Send data message to own Android phone without msisdn

Tags: android, sim-card

I know that we can send data messages from sms manager API to other phones but want to know how to send data message to my own android phone without any MSISDN. Basically, I want to send some binary commands to my SIM card. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want to send some data from your phone to your SIM (inside the phone)? Or you want to send something from a server?

Comment: I want to send some data from my phone to my sim. No external server.